# Getting Run-time error '13': Type mismatch when I run following macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I am not quite familiar with syntax. I have made an excel macro that will identify the background of current cell and append the current value with the name of background color. So if a cell has blue background and value 1000, macro should replace the value in cell as '1000 blue'. Following is the code I wrote.

```
Sub coloridentifier()
Dim Myrange As Range
Dim Mycell As Range
Dim Myvalue As String
Set Myrange = Selection
For Each Mycell In Myrange.Rows
    Myvalue = Mycell.Value
    If Mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
        Mycell.Value = Myvalue & " Green"
    ElseIf Mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(184, 204, 228) Then
        Mycell.Value = Myvalue & " Blue"
    ElseIf Mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0) Then
        Mycell.Value = Myvalue & " Red"
    End If
Next Mycell
End Sub
```

The debugger points to following line:

```
Myvalue = Mycell.Value
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The error suggests that `Myvalue` and `Mycell.Value` are different types. You may need to cast the cell's value to a string, eg. `Str(Mycell.Value)`

Comment: How much columns do you select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `For Each Mycell In Myrange.Rows` this line to

```
For Each Mycell In Myrange
```

When you are using `Myrange.Rows` Then the sub will loop to row of your set range. When you will use only `Myrange` then it will loop to cells of set range. Also remove `.value` from `Mycell.Value` because when you will use `.value` then it will take only values (numeric values) from cell. If you want to keep `.value` then change variable type `Integer` or `Long` from `String` like `Dim Myvalue As Integer`.

So, full sub will be

```
Sub coloridentifier()
Dim Myrange As Range
Dim Mycell As Range
Dim Myvalue As Variant
Set Myrange = Selection
For Each Mycell In Myrange
    Myvalue = Mycell
    If Mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
        Mycell.Value = Myvalue & " Green"
    ElseIf Mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then
        Mycell.Value = Myvalue & " Blue"
    ElseIf Mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0) Then
        Mycell.Value = Myvalue & " Red"
    End If
Next Mycell
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually `Range.Value` returns a `Variant` and can thus be anything than can be inserted in a Cell.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare a variable for the cell value, you can just do it like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub coloridentifier()

    Dim Myrange As Range
    Dim Mycell As Range

    Set Myrange = Selection
    For Each Mycell In Myrange
        If Mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
            Mycell = Mycell & " Green"
        ElseIf Mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(184, 204, 228) Then
            Mycell = Mycell & " Blue"
        ElseIf Mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0) Then
            Mycell = Mycell & " Red"
        End If
    Next Mycell

End Sub
```

Though I'd avoid using the `Set Myrange = Selection` and declare your range by giving it the adresses.

Comment: Thanks. that's helpful. Your solution works. Though the problem in my code as addressed by @Harun24HR the problem was with my For each Mycell in Myrange.Rows line. It worked as soon as I removed rows from that line.

Answer (score 0):

### You're trying to assign an array to a string variable

`Cells` is a collection of `Range` objects, so are `Rows` and `Columns`. Whenever you loop through `Range.Rows` and you have more than 1 column in a row, the `.Value` property will be an array and you can't assign one to a string variable.